# XPath choose one if both exist

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have something like

```
<li class="ProductPrice">
    <span class="Regular Price">80.00</span>
    <span class="Sale Price">50.00</span>
</li>
<li class="ProductPrice">
    <span class="Regular Price">100.00</span>
</li>
```

where some items might not have the `Sale Price` span.

I would like to extract the current retail price, where I would select the `Sale Price` or if both Sale and `Regular Price` exist, choose `Sale Price` only.

I'm new to XPath, so I'm not sure how this if-else could be translated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to extract the current retail price, where I would select
>   the Sale Price or if both Sale and Regular Price exist, choose Sale
>   Price only.

If you know that the Sale price will always come after the Regular price, use the XPath expression

```
span[@class = 'Regular Price' or @class = 'Sale Price'][last()]
```

In XPath 2.0 you can use this approach even if you don't know the order:

```
(span[@class = 'Sale Price'], span[@class = 'Regular Price'])[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

An XSLT-1.0 solution is a bit more complicated:

```
<xsl:template match="li">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="span/@class='Sale Price'">
            <xsl:value-of select="span[@class='Sale Price']" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="span[@class='Regular Price']" />            
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

So if you have XPath-2.0 or above available you could use the following:

```
<xsl:template match="li">
    <xsl:value-of select="if (span/@class='Sale Price') then (span[@class='Sale Price']) else (span[@class='Regular Price'])" />            
</xsl:template>
```

**The output of both solutions is the same:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
50.00
100.00
```

The logic is not exactly what you desired, but it is close to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **lxml** module in python. It is **by far the easiest** module which I have used.

```
from lxml import html

data = '''<li class="ProductPrice">
              <span class="Regular Price">80.00</span>
              <span class="Sale Price">50.00</span>
          </li>
          <li class="ProductPrice">
              <span class="Regular Price">100.00</span>
          </li>
       '''

#make the html object
tree = html.fromstring(data)
li = tree.xpath('//li') #get all the li tags

for i in li:

    sp = i.xpath('.//span[contains(@class,"Sale Price")]/text()')
    rp = i.xpath('.//span[contains(@class,"Regular Price")]/text()')

    if sp:
        print('Price is :',sp[0])
    else:
        print('Price is :',rp[0])
```

What I did was, to extract **sale price** and check if it is there. **If** it is present then program will print that **else** program will print regular price.

### Note

- Remember to put **(.)** in the xpath when playing with seperate elements.
- The result of the xpath **always comes as list**.

For any query do put up a comment.

Comment: When you use `contains` within `xpath` then you don't need to use the compound class names, as in `Regular Price`. Try something like `.//span[contains(@class,"Regular")]/text()` instead.

Comment: @SIM Thanks for mentioning.